# How to Make bold text in PHP exported .xls file

Tags: php, xls

I am working in core PHP.
I need to make header text in bold format and remains normal text format.
The .xls file will be export from PHP.

**I am not using any plug-in in my project. I need to complete this without using any plug-in.
But i unable to solve this.**

My code as follows,

```
//header part cration
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($exe))
{
    //need to set bold. But it is not working. it giving error
    //$header .= "<b>".$r['question']."</b>"."\t ";

    $header .=.$r['question']."\t ";
}

//body part cration
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($exe))
{
    $data .= $r['answer']."\t ";
    //code continuous...
}
```

and Exporting code as follows,

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reports.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\n\n$data";
```

Exporting file working fine. But i unable to make headers are bold.

Please any help much be appreciated.

Comment: Look into using [PHP Excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It will make your life much easier.

Comment: @njk please i need to do this without using any plug in.

Comment: Why do you need to do this without any plugins (you actually mean extra libraries)?

Comment: @vijay.s Then you need to research how Excel makes a cell bold.

Comment: @JamWaffles Client told me to do without using any plug-in. So i unable to use any plug-in in my project

Comment: I don't think your client understands what they're talking about. This is made _far_ easier by using an existing library, and there's one out there for almost any license.

Answer (score 2):

One potential option would be to have your PHP code generate an HTML table model that includes your formatting on specific cells. Then have PHP save the file as an XLS document and Excel should be able to open that with the formatting applied.

It might not be the most elegant solution, but it [looks like has been done before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281902/1028949).

[I can see why many people suggest using a plugin.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3522608/1028949)